# How to insert number in struct array (Swift4)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, insert

My code is not working. All I am trying to do is get the number inserted into the struct's internal array. Right now this is not working:

```
@IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {
    bad.numbers.insert(0, at: 0)
}


struct bad {
    var numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your numbers property as static. Btw it is Swift convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter:

```
struct Bad {
    static var numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
}
```

And to insert elements at index 0, you need to call it like this :

```
Bad.numbers.insert(0, at: 0)

print(Bad.numbers)  // "[0, 1, 2, 3]\n"
```